# Função jQuery que fecha o campo de pesquisa ao clicar em Esc

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

No site em que estou desenvolvendo, há um campo de pesquisa que só mostra o `input` quando clica em cima do botão.

Agora quero fechar o `input` quando clicar na tecla <kbd>Esc</kbd> (quando o foco estiver no campo). Fiz uma função em jQuery, porém não está funcionando:

**FUNÇÃO:**

```
$('#campo-pesquisa').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 27) $('#fechar-campo').click();
});
```

**CÓDIGO HTML**

```
<div class="form-pesquisa">
                    <form class="input-group" id="campo-pesquisa" action="{{ url }}busca">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control border-right-0" id="input-pesquisa" name="q"
                               aria-label="Campo de busca" placeholder="O que deseja procurar?">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="search">
                                <button type="submit">
                                    <span class="ocultaVisualmente">Buscar</span>
                                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="close-pesquisa">
                                <button type="reset" id="fechar-campo">
                                    <span class="ocultaVisualmente">Fechar Campo de Pesquisa</span>
                                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: E o código que trata do `click` em `#fechar-campo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `keypress` só detecta teclas com caracteres printáveis (letras, números, espaço etc).

**[Documentação MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Use `keydown` que detecta todas as teclas, logo a tecla <kbd>ESC</kbd> será detectada:

```
$('#campo-pesquisa').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 27) $('#fechar-campo').click();
});
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito Obrigado!